# merge_array returns null if one or more of arrays is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I will give you quick run down of what I am doing.

I am using wordpress with the [advanced custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. This is a php based question because these `get_field()` fields contain object arrays.

```
$gallery_location   = get_field('gallery_location');
$gallery_studio = get_field('gallery_studio');
```

For example `$gallery_location` when dumped will return this...

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(126)
    ["alt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
    string(33) "CBR1000RR STD Supersport 2014 001"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["mime_type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["url"]=>
    string(94) "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/CBR1000RR-STD-Supersport-2014-001.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(7360)
    ["height"]=>
    int(4912)
  }
... on so fourth
}
```

I am then using merge_array to merge both objects...

```
$gallery_location = get_field('gallery_location');
$gallery_studio = get_field('gallery_studio');

$downloads = array_merge( $gallery_location, $gallery_studio );
```

I am merging multiple arrays but if one of the arrays is empty then this is causing the merge array to return null entirely!

My question is how can I stop merge_array returning null is some of the arrays are empty?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

---

@zessx

This is what I am returning...

```
$gallery_location   = get_field( 'gallery_location' );
$gallery_studio     = get_field( 'gallery_studio' );

$downloads = array_merge( $gallery_location, $gallery_studio );

var_dump($gallery_location);

var_dump($gallery_studio);

var_dump($downloads);
```

and these are the results of dumps above in same order...

```
string(0) ""
```

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(126)
    ["alt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
    string(33) "CBR1000RR STD Supersport 2014 001"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["mime_type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["url"]=>
    string(94) "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/CBR1000RR-STD-Supersport-2014-001.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(7360)
    ["height"]=>
    int(4912)
  }
... on so fourth
}
```

```
NULL
```

As you can see `$downloads` is still returning null, if I try and use both your solution below it does not work?

Comment: Seems good. Have you tried your `var_dump($gallery_location); var_dump($gallery_studio);` just before your `array_merge` ?

Comment: @zessx - I've just updated my question, it's becuase one of the arrays are empty which cause merge to return null overall :/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`array_merge` only accepts arrays as parameters. If one of your parameters is null, it will raise an error :

> Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #x is not an array...

This error won't be raised if one of the arrays is empty. An empty array is still an array.

Two options :

**1/ Force the type to be `array`**

```
$downloads = array_merge( (array)$gallery_location, (array)$gallery_studio );
```

**2/ Check if variables are arrays**

```
$downloads = array();
if(is_array($gallery_location))
    $downloads = array_merge($downloads, $gallery_location);
if(is_array($gallery_studio ))
    $downloads = array_merge($downloads, $gallery_studio);
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7512b59a0e08de604fcb1a87e8ba68d2fb1e57f3)

Comment: This does not seem to result the null issue, please see my question above at the bottom, I have dumped everything so you can see what empty arrays are returning. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: There was a typo (`downlads` instead of `downloads`), but it should work, [see this PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7512b59a0e08de604fcb1a87e8ba68d2fb1e57f3)

Comment: I love you so much dude this now works - sorry I was concentration, it was a cheap copy and paste on my behalf. Thanks for you help man. +1

Comment: Adding `(array)` is definitely the nicer way to handle this +1

Comment: Just a note, since the `?:` operator is available now, one can also do `array_merge($a1 ?: [], $a2 ?: [], $a3 ?: [], $a4 ?: []);` which is essentially the same as casting to `(array)` but a bit less typing

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following way for merger your arrays:

```
$c = (array)$a + (array)$b
```