# PHP save multiple arrays values into one

Tags: php, arrays

**How can I add values of the three arrays into one?**

When I do like this

```
$response["data"] =  $data + $user_poi + $user_mileage;
```

it does add the arrays into one but not the complete array. Consider the following:

```
$data = {data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, data 5, data 6, data, 7 data 8}
$user_poi = {poi 1}
$user_mileage {mileage 1, mileage 2, mileage 3, mileage 4}
```

If I write: `$response["data"] =  $data + $user_poi + $user_mileage;`

It gives me: `{data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, data 5, data 6, data, 7 data 8}`

If I write: `$response["data"] = $user_poi + $user_mileage + $data;`

It gives me: `{poi 1, mileage 2, mileage 3, mileage 4, data 5, data 6, data, 7 data 8}`

What I want is to write: `$response["data"] = $user_poi + $user_mileage + $data;`

And get the result: `{poi 1, mileage 1, mileage 2, mileage 3, mileage 4, data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, data 5, data 6, data, 7 data 8}`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php

Comment: Also, you are basically asking two separate questions as one. I recommend you to split them into two actual questions (remove the second part from here, post it as a new question).

Comment: "Consider the following" is not valid PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the first part of your question. For the second part, I strongly suggest post that as a new, separate question and remove it from here.

> How can I add values of the three arrays into one?

Try [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$data = ["data 1", "data 2", "data 3"];
$poi = ["poi 1", "poi 1", "poi 3"];
$mileage = ["mileage 1", "mileage 2", "mileage 3"];

$response = array_merge($data, $poi, $mileage);
```

After this, `$response` will look like this:

```
array(
  "data 1",
  "data 2",
  "data 3",
  "poi 1",
  "poi 2",
  "poi 3",
  "mileage 1",
  "mileage 2",
  "mileage 3"
)
```

**Why did `+` not work though?**

Check the question [*+ operator for array in PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php).

To summarize the well written answer from there, using `+`, keys that exist in both arrays will be filled with the values from the array on the left-hand side, that's why you never see all of the expected elements in your output.

***Update*: What if one of the arrays is `null`?**

Check the question [*merge_array returns null if one or more of arrays is empty?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711491/merge-array-returns-null-if-one-or-more-of-arrays-is-empty)

Basically, if your input arrays could be `null`, you can explicitly cast them to arrays to make sure null values will become empty arrays:

```
$response = array_merge((array)$data, (array)$poi, (array)$mileage);
```

Comment: This worked good. The issue now, if one of these arrays is null it does not return anything at all!!!

Comment: Jumana, you should turn on all warnings. Anyway, check this answer for a solution to the `null` problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19712372/3316645 (basically, just cast all parameters for `array_merge` to array, this way `null` values will become empty arrays)